# Python: dealing with ampersands in URLs & file paths

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, path, ampersand

I'm using a Python script to process requested PDFs before presenting them to the browser. The path to the PDF is given as a URL parameter. One of the safety measures before trying to open the PDF is to make sure that the path is within the webroot and that the file ends with '.pdf'. To this end, I split the requested path into an array of its directories plus the file name. This is working fine in most cases...

However, at least one of the possible paths contains an ampersand in a directory name. When the processor reaches this directory, it short-circuits at the ampersand and reports that the requested file is not a PDF. I'm dumping the array of directories and I can see that the element containing the directory name with the ampersand is truncated just before it: 'a & b' becomes 'a '. Here's the code that tests the file extension:

```
if splitpath[len(splitpath) - 1][-4:].lower() != '.pdf':
  print "Content-type: text/plain\n"
  print "Requested file is not a PDF."
  print splitpath
  sys.exit()
```

If I try to request `?file=/alwaysbrand/pdfs/a & b/myfile.pdf`, this code returns:

```
Requested file is not a PDF.
['var', 'www', 'alwaysbrand', 'pdfs', 'a ']
```

Any idea how I can keep Python from choking when it hits that ampersand? Unfortunately, renaming the directories is not an option in this case.

**EDIT**: Before doing anything else, I've tried assigning the path with urllib.unquote_plus, but it still stops parsing at the ampersand:

```
fullpath = urllib.unquote_plus(os.path.abspath(form["file"].value[1:]))
print "Content-type: text/plain\n"
print fullpath
```

returns `/var/www/alwaysbrand/pdfs/a` when passing `?file=/pdfs/a%20&%20b/myfile.pdf` (the space is properly unquoted, just not the ampersand or anything after it).

Comment: Are you requesting this over HTTP, if you are try encoding your URLs see urllib.urlencode(f) e.g. 
?file=/alwaysbrand/pdfs/a%20%26%20b/myfile.pdf

Comment: good call, but no go, see above :(

Comment: What value does form["file"].value[1:] have? I get /home/dan/?file=/alwaysbrand/pdfs/a & b/myfile.pdf when passing in path = "?file=/alwaysbrand/pdfs/a%20&%20b/myfile.pdf"
fullpath = urllib.unquote_plus(os.path.abspath(path))
print fullpath

Comment: `fullpath = urllib.unquote_plus(os.path.abspath(path))` returns `<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'path' is not defined`. `print os.path.abspath(form['file'].value[1:])` returns `/var/www/alwaysbrand/pdfs/a ` (again, the space is parsed but the ampersand is not).

Comment: If you look at my previous comment I set path = "?file=/alwaysbrand/pdfs/a%20&%20b/myfile.pdf" first

Comment: Can you try print form['file'].value[1:]

Comment: Oops, I missed the point of the previous comment. Setting the path as a string and using urllib.unquote_plus() works the same as it does for you (path comes through fine, no ampersand issue). When printing just form['file'].value[1:] (and using the URL param instead of an internal string) it truncates at the ampersand.

Comment: So where does form['file'].value[1:]  come from? an HTTP post request? Can we see some code for this? looks to me like it gets truncated somewhere before the code we are looking at.

Comment: `form` is the HTTP request (GET) elements: `form = cgi.FieldStorage()`. The file parameter is the browser's request for a file on the server's filesystem. If I replace the & with a %26 in the GET request, the script works properly, so it looks like the form parser is seeing it as the start of another parameter (vs. part of file=) if it's not URL encoded. However, I don't have control over how the link is written.

Comment: Sounds to me like an incorrect URL if you have no control over it there is not much you can do.